# A structure that stores its fields by size

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, struct, variadic-templates

I would like to know how can I do the following in C++:

Consider these classes :

`C1 < C2 < C3 < ... < Cn,`  `Ci < Cj` means `sizeof(Ci) < sizeof(Cj)`

I want a structure that uses variadic templates as a sequence of `Ci`'s,

`OrderBySize<AnySequenceOfCis>`, for example : `OrderBySize<C1,C2,C3,...,Cn>` or 
 `OrderBySize<C2,C1,C3,C4,...,Cn>` ... all possible combinations

and gives the following structure as a result :

```
class result{
  Cn elem1;
  Cn-1 elem2;
  .
  .
  .
  C1 elemn;
}
```

I read [this article](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/), it shows how we can define a `Tuple<typename ...T>`, however, this is different, much more difficult to implement and very useful.

**EDIT :**

`order_by_size<T1, ..., Tn>` would **contain** a tuple of the ordered combination of `T1, ..., Tn`

However I don't want the user to know that I am ordering the fields, the user would use it like a tuple. And thus, in order to access the fields, the user will use :

`template<typename... Tn>
get<size_t>(const MyStructure<Tn ...>& m)` to get the `size_t`'th element which is has an other index in the new `tuple`.

[image]

Comment: Still not clear. Show example usage of this, with both access via user-defined order and by sorted order.

Comment: Oh, I see why it is not clear. Actually, I want Order_by_size to be the struct that contains data, not only an empty struct that contains the defintion of the tuple.

Comment: And in order to access the data of my `order_by_size struct`, I will have a function `get<>` that works a little bit like `std::get<>`

Comment: still not clear. In what order should this `get<>` work?

Comment: in the order gived by the user when he is declaring his variable

Comment: So, you want `std::get` to work in the order of descending sizes, and `get` to work in the initial user-specified order?

Comment: Exactly, actually I won't need std::get at all, I will make the tuple private, so he can only use `get` to access data. I made a drawing, but you got it already

Comment: Then how are you going to use the descending-size order?

Comment: I am using it only to store them that way

Comment: Why do you need them to be stored this way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80299/discussion-between-othman-benchekroun-and-lisyarus).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically this problem reduces to just sorting a list of types based on a given comparator. Once you have that, everything else follows. So this answer is just the sorting part. We'll start with a typelist:

```
template <typename...>
struct typelist {
    using type = typelist;
};
```

I'm going to assume a bunch of metafunctions which are very short (`head`, `tail`, `concat`, `size`). I will omit them for brevity.

So let's just jump into writing merge sort:

```
template <typename TL, typename Cmp = LessSize>
struct sort
{
    using left_right = typename split<TL, size<TL>::value/2>::type;
    using left = typename sort<head_t<left_right>, Cmp>::type;
    using right = typename sort<head_t<tail_t<left_right>>, Cmp>::type;

    using type = typename merge<left, right, Cmp>::type;
};

// base case for exactly 1 element
template <typename T, typename Cmp>
struct sort<typelist<T>, Cmp> {
    using type = typelist<T>;
};

// potentially add a base case for exactly 2 elements here?
```

The general structure here should look familiar. We split our typelist, `TL`, into two equal parts, sort both, and then merge. Of course, this is metaprogramming, so everything is unnecessarily complicated.

Let's start with `split`. `split` takes a typelist and a size, and returns a typelist of two typelists: the first having the given size, and the second being the remainder:

```
template <typename A, typename B, size_t N>
struct split_impl
    : std::conditional<
        size<A>::value < N,
        split_impl<concat_t<A, typelist<head_t<B>>>, tail_t<B>, N>,
        typelist<A, B>
        >::type
{ };

template <typename TL, size_t N>
struct split
    : split_impl<typelist<>, TL, N>
{ };
```

So that gives us `left` and `right` (at least once we apply `head_t<>` and `head_t<tail_t<>>`). All that's left is the `merge` step. I'm using the Boost MPL idea of what a metafunction class is, so `LessSize` is:

```
struct LessSize {
    template <typename A, typename B>
    using apply = std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof(A) < sizeof(B)>;
};
```

`merge` just has to walk both typelists and pick the smallest element based on the comparator between the two typelists. First, we'll start with all of our base cases:

```
template <typename L, typename R, typename Cmp>
struct merge;

// R empty
template <typename... T, typename Cmp>
struct merge<typelist<T...>, typelist<>, Cmp> {
    using type = typelist<T...>;
};

// L empty
template <typename... T, typename Cmp>
struct merge<typelist<>, typelist<T...>, Cmp> {
    using type = typelist<T...>;
};
```

And then the recursive step, which is somewhat ugly:

```
template <typename A, typename... As, typename B, typename... Bs, typename Cmp> 
struct merge<typelist<A, As...>, typelist<B, Bs...>, Cmp>
: std::conditional<
        Cmp::template apply<A, B>::value,
        concat_t<typelist<A>, typename merge<typelist<As...>, typelist<B, Bs...>, Cmp>::type>,
        concat_t<typelist<B>, typename merge<typelist<A, As...>, typelist<Bs...>, Cmp>::type>
        >::type
{ };
```

Basically, given two typelists, `{A, As...}` and `{B, Bs...}`, we select the smallest based on `Cmp`, and that's the side we're popping the element off of. If `Cmp::apply<A,B>`, then we're concatenating `A` with the result of merging `{As...}` with `{B, Bs...}`. And vice versa.

And that's all she wrote:

```
template <typename T>
struct TD;

int main()
{
    using T = sort<typelist<int, double, char, float>, LessSize>::type;
    TD<T> r;
}

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:131:11: error: aggregate 'TD<typelist<char, float, int, double> > r' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
     TD<T> r;
           ^
```

Once you have the sorted types, making a tuple is straightforward:

```
template <template <typename...> class C>
struct meta_quote {
    template <typename... T>
    using apply = C<T...>;
};

template <typename F, typename TL>
struct meta_apply;

template <typename F, typename... T>
struct meta_apply<F, typelist<T...>> {
    using type = typename F::template apply<T...>;
};

template <typename... T>
struct my_tuple
: meta_apply<meta_quote<std::tuple>,
             typename sort<typelist<T...>>::type
             >::type;
{ 
    using base_tuple = meta_apply<...>;
};
```

Now just add overloads for `get<>` on `my_tuple<T...>`:

```
template <size_t I, typename... T>
auto get(my_tuple<T...>& t) {
    using type = std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<T...>>;
    return std::get<type>(static_cast<typename my_tuple<T...>::base_type&>(t));
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is a looong answer, even omitting a lot of code. Still, was fun to solve :)

Comment: Oh god, that's amazing, I can see why it was fun (and I am not kidding)

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not the most efficient implementation (it uses cyclic permutation of types to determine the one with the largest size), and may contain errors, but the whole idea should be clear. The result is `std::tuple` with types ordered by descending size. The main function checks if it actually works (and it works on my gcc-4.8.2).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <iomanip>

constexpr std::size_t max (std::size_t x, std::size_t y)
{
   return (x < y) ? y : x;
}

template <typename ... Ts>
struct max_size;

template < >
struct max_size < >
{
       static constexpr std::size_t result = 0;
};

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct max_size <T, Ts...>
{
       static constexpr std::size_t result = max(sizeof(T), max_size<Ts...>::result);
};

template <typename R, typename ... Ts>
struct order_by_size_impl;

template <bool M, typename R, typename ... Ts>
struct order_by_size_helper;

template <typename ... Rs, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct order_by_size_helper<true, std::tuple<Rs...>, T, Ts...>
    : order_by_size_impl<std::tuple<Rs..., T>, Ts...>
{ };

template <typename ... Rs, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct order_by_size_helper<false, std::tuple<Rs...>, T, Ts...>
    : order_by_size_impl<std::tuple<Rs...>, Ts..., T>
{ };

template <typename ... Rs, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct order_by_size_impl<std::tuple<Rs...>, T, Ts...>
    : order_by_size_helper<sizeof(T) >= max_size<Ts...>::result, std::tuple<Rs...>, T, Ts...>
{ };

template <typename ... Rs>
struct order_by_size_impl<std::tuple<Rs...>>
{
       typedef std::tuple<Rs...> result;
};

template <typename ... Ts>
struct order_by_size
    : order_by_size_impl<std::tuple<>, Ts...>
{ };

struct test
{
   std::uint8_t data[128];
};

template <std::size_t I, typename T, typename R>
bool check (R const & r)
{
   return std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(std::get<I>(r))>::type>::type, T>::value;
}

int main ( )
{
   order_by_size<std::uint8_t, std::uint32_t, std::uint16_t, std::uint64_t, test>::result r;
   std::cout << std::boolalpha;
   std::cout << check<0, test>(r) << std::endl;
   std::cout << check<1, std::uint64_t>(r) << std::endl;
   std::cout << check<2, std::uint32_t>(r) << std::endl;
   std::cout << check<3, std::uint16_t>(r) << std::endl;
   std::cout << check<4, std::uint8_t>(r) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: how can I make `get<size_t>` return the appriopriate field (in the order given by the user), for example in your test, `get<1>(r)` would return a `std::uint32_t`, not a `std::uint64_t`. I think I must keep track of the first order to do that, but I can't see how

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun could you write a bit more, probably with examples? It's not vary clear to me what you are asking.